# Hash distribution on identity column

Tags: azure-synapse

Creating a table in Azure SQL Data Warehouse, I would like to make a hash distribution on an identity column, but get an error that

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table_ff4d8c5d544f4e26a31dbe71b44851cb_11' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Is this not possible? And if not, why? And is there a work-around? (And where does this odd table name come from?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use an IDENTITY column as the hash distributed column in your table.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-identity#limitations

In SQLDW the name you give to your table is its logical name not its physical name. Logical metadata such as table names is maintained centrally on the control node so that operations such as table renames are quick and painless. However, SQLDW is still bound by the rules of table creation - we need to make sure the table name is unique both now and in the future. Therefore the physical names contain guids to deliver that uniqueness.

Saying that, the error you have here is not ideal. It would be helpful if you can post a repro so that we can improve the experience for you.

You are also welcome to post a feature request on our uservoice channel for hash distribution on the IDENTITY column. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll switch to GUID as my surrogate key instead of an IDENTITY column - that should do the trick.

Comment: As to repro, it seems there has been an update since I created the table last week, because now it is no longer possible - I get this message: "Identity column is not supported as distribution column.". This means that the problem I had in this post will no longer be possible to experience for anyone, because they cannot create a table where the identity column is distribution column.